# How do I replace weather strips on our outside doors?

Tags: doors, weatherstripping

We have a rather annoying cat who has scratched all of our outside doors and ripped the weather stripping with her claws.

How do I go about replacing this stripping and are there any weather strips on the market that may be less prone to being torn up in the future?

Comment: Would be helpful to see a picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely would be helpful to see a picture, but something like this [under-door weather stripping](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BD8LC0) attaches directly underneath the door and I doubt your cat would be able to get to it.
[image]